# How to wrap a synchronous function to async function in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await

am using a synchronous 3rd function which I cannot modify, such as:

```
public void startDoSth(Action<string> onDone)
```

`startDoSth` spawn a new thread to do the job, and returns immediately, and when the thing is done, my `onDone` function would be called.

I'd like to write an asynchronous method like below to wrap it:

```
public async Task<string> doSthAsync();
```

So, someone can call it like this:

```
string s = await doSthAsync()
onDone(s)
```

In `doSthasync()` I call `startDoSth()` to do the real thing.
But I have no idea how to write the `doSthAsync()`.

Could anyone tell if it is possible and how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887255/wrap-a-callback-into-async-task

Comment: Why do you need this method when you can `Task.Run`?

Comment: @asaf92 What would `Task.Run` achieve here? The work is already being run on a new thread according to the OP.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought the `onDone` argument was the actual work being done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) to convert that into TAP:

```
Task<string> DoSthAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    startDoSth(tcs.SetResult);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

`SetResult` completes the returned `Task` (and sets the result), so that can be passed as the callback function.